# beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents does not work for AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have been trying for this for last several weeks. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. MPRemoteCommandCenter does not even show any thing when I use AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers. Please check the code below:

```
- (void) activateAudioSessionWithPlayOption:(bool) playingOption withRecordingOption:(bool) recordingOption {
NSError *audioErr;
self.mAudioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

[self.mAudioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers  error:&audioErr];
[self.mAudioSession setActive:YES error:nil];

MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
[commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand setEnabled:YES];
[commandCenter.playCommand setEnabled:YES];
[commandCenter.pauseCommand setEnabled:YES];
[commandCenter.stopCommand setEnabled:YES];

[commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(pttPulseAction)];
[commandCenter.playCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(pttPlayAction)];
[commandCenter.pauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(pttPauseAction)];
[commandCenter.stopCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(pttStopAction)];


MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *infoCenter = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
[infoCenter setNowPlayingInfo:@{MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:@"TESTAPP"}];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
}
```

But it does started working if I declare my category as withOptions:kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, like this:

```
- (void) activateAudioSessionWithPlayOption:(bool) playingOption withRecordingOption:(bool) recordingOption {
NSError *audioErr;
self.mAudioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

[self.mAudioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers  error:&audioErr];
[self.mAudioSession setActive:YES error:nil];

MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
[commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand setEnabled:YES];
[commandCenter.playCommand setEnabled:YES];
[commandCenter.pauseCommand setEnabled:YES];
[commandCenter.stopCommand setEnabled:YES];

[commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(pttPulseAction)];
[commandCenter.playCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(pttPlayAction)];
[commandCenter.pauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(pttPauseAction)];
[commandCenter.stopCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(pttStopAction)];


MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *infoCenter = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
[infoCenter setNowPlayingInfo:@{MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:@"TESTAPP"}];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can't I use AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers for receiving remoteControlEvents?